# IDEA UML image Not a polyline but a curve

Tags: intellij-idea, uml

[image]

for example：https://www.cnblogs.com/linxuannihao/gallery/image/430490.html

What should I do?

I want this: [image]

Comment: It's by design in the current release. Why would you want a different line style? You can submit a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: Corresponding feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-302924